# pyinstaller gives error while forming python exe

Tags: python, pyinstaller, pyqt6

```
File "c:\users\\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\hook-PyQt5.py", line 11, in <module>
    from PyInstaller.utils.hooks.qt import pyqt5_library_info, \
  File "c:\users\\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\hooks\qt.py", line 162, in <module>
    pyqt5_library_info = QtLibraryInfo('PyQt5')
  File "c:\users\\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\hooks\qt.py", line 54, in __init__
    if hooks.is_module_satisfies("PyQt5 >= 5.15.4"):
  File "c:\users\\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\hooks\__init__.py", line 502, in is_module_satisfies
    version = get_module_attribute(module_name, version_attr)
  File "c:\users\\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\hooks\__init__.py", line 352, in get_module_attribute
    raise AttributeError(
AttributeError: Module 'PyQt5' has no attribute '__version__'
```

getting errors during exe formation, how can I fix these errors.
I have installed pyqt6 through pip install pyqt6

Comment: It seems that pyinstaller does not support PyQt6 yet

Comment: oh.. what about pyqt5?

Comment: Also I had to use python 3.6.7, earlier i tried with python 3.8

Answer (score 0):

Its working in python version 3.8.8